# Why creating a Stripe customer.id fails within AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I am using the [Stripe/NodeJS library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) to generate a Stripe customer id when a user is created:

```js
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 const newUser = JSON.parse(event.body);

 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  email: newUser.emailAddress,
 });

 return customer.id;
};
```

I thought that the code is pretty straightforward and almost a duplicate to the library's README example, however, the lambda execution hits the **stripe.customers.create** and never completes, the lambda eventually times out (the lambda is NodeJS 12.x).

Thoughts on what I am missing in order to get this to work?

Comment: Do you have any error or does it simply hang and then times out? If it just hangs, is by chance your lambda function in a VPC? Consider adding a timeout to the Stripe object as detailed [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#configuration), if it's a network issue on the Lambda's side then it'll at least timeout.

Comment: Yes, it is within a VPC.  My assumption was that the Stripe create method called https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers under the hood and my VPC allows egress traffic.

Comment: Check that the Security Group associated to your lambda function has the proper egress policies (I assume it'll be HTTP/HTTPS towards any). If it does then double check by trying to make a simple GET request to any other host that it's not Stripe.